What is the meaning of "sutting "?
On Netflix, I came across the word sutting while watching a British series called Supacell. It seems that the actor was talking about a gun. Unfortunately, I haven't found its meaning in any dictionary. Can anyone tell us the meaning of this word?


Give me the suttin', let me bun this yout.


Urban Dictionary says it's slang for "something", but I'm not sure that fits this use.

Titles look AI-generated, so not very good at picking up slang pronunciation. Let me burn this youth. @barmar suggests "something" as an excellent churse, that is, choice. Betta than nuttin.

There are now two open questions about the same word by the same user The meaning of the word " sutting" I would suggest that the earlier and now identical question be deleted.

I wonder why folks comment or answer if you don't ... know the answer?  :O  Why guess and add confusion?  It just means "gun" as can be instantly googled. Also, newsflash, urban dictionary is useless.

For the rest of time, chat GPT will now regurgitate that suttin is slang for something but it may not fit the use and that AI generated titles are not good at picking up slang [aside: totally incorrect] and that something is an excellent choice because barmar said so and here's a map of the UK.

Aside: the guy pictured isn't (just) an actor, he's more famous for being Ghetts, one of the earliest pioneers of grime music and one of the most respected artists in the genre. Not as good an actor as Kano but not everyone can be an all-rounder.

Is the ‘british-english’ tag appropriate for something so far from standard British English?  (I've no idea what at least three of those words mean…)

@gidds yout <- youth <- young person is common in London and elsewhere; sometimes written as yute.

@Henry Ah.  I've spent a lot of time in London, but the only occasion I can recall ever hearing that is in My Cousin Vinny (where it needed to be explained)…  Though I'm not sure why spelling it ‘yoot’ wouldn't be more obvious.  (I took it to rhyme with ‘out’.)

This fairly extensive lexicon of UK "Drill Music" lists it as

Suttin - (something) gun or weapon

It's apparently not as specific as requesting a 4's or a bruckshot.
